# Aggregation Column must be in Group By

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql i can't execute this code

```
SELECT name, SUM(sws) as sws,  SUM(sws) over (partition by sws)  swsrange FROM professoren
JOIN vorlesungen on persnr = gelesenvon
group by name
order by sws desc
```

The Error code is this:

> FEHLER:  Spalte »vorlesungen.sws« muss in der GROUP-BY-Klausel erscheinen oder in einer Aggregatfunktion verwendet werden
>   LINE 1: SELECT name, SUM(sws) as sws,  SUM(sws) over (partition by s...

which means he wants "sws" must be in the group by or in a aggregation function (which it actually is).

**UPDATE:**

i changed it to

```
SELECT name, SUM(sws) as swscount,  SUM(sws) over (partition by name)   swsrange FROM professoren
JOIN vorlesungen on persnr = gelesenvon
group by name, sws
```

the output is:

> Augustinus,2,2|Kant,8,4|Popper,2,2|Russel,2,5|Russel,6,5|Sokrates,2,6|Sokrates,8,6

but it should be like the first Column is the name, the second is the sum() of all lessons he gives and the third is like a ranking who has the most lessons:

> Sokrates,10,1|Kant,8,2|Russel,8,2|Augustinus,2,3|Popper,2,3

i can't see the issue here.
thanks for your help.

Comment: `partition by sws` - you use sws to partition over it, so it needs to go to group by just like "name". Or better remove group by and add partition by name to the window?..

Comment: Can you write some sample data, highlighting what is your desidered output? (please write sample data in text - not images)

Comment: @etsa i updated the sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified   `SUM(sws) over (partition by sws)`  but sws is not specified in `GROUP BY`.

After your edit of question, could it be what you are looking for?:

```
DROP TABLE T2;
CREATE TABLE T2 (NAME VARCHAR(20), SWSCOUNT INT)
;
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES ('Augustinus',2), ('Kant',8), ('Popper',2), ('Russel',2), ('Russel',6),('Sokrates',2),('Sokrates',8);

SELECT * FROM T2;

SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY swscount DESC) 
FROM (SELECT NAME, SUM(SWSCOUNT) AS SWSCOUNT 
      FROM T2
      GROUP BY NAME) X
```

Ouput:

```
    name    swscount
1   Augustinus  2
2   Kant    8
3   Popper  2
4   Russel  2
5   Russel  6
6   Sokrates    2
7   Sokrates    8

    name    swscount    dense_rank
1   Sokrates    10  1
2   Kant    8   2
3   Russel  8   2
4   Popper  2   3
5   Augustinus  2   3
```

Comment: but then its not anymore grouped by the "name"

Comment: You can't do what you wrote in your query. Can you write some sample data, highlighting what is your desidered output? (please write sample data in text - not images)

Comment: wow! wonderful, i was trying this all day long! :D
great idea to do this in two steps! thank you very much!

Comment: @Kjenos  really nothing "great": this is quite normal for who knows a bit sql  :-)

Comment: thanks anyway, for me its great. my teacher doesn't explain things well and doesn't give tutorials at all, so it's quite hard for me. I appreciate this alot :)

Comment: well, you got internet... it is not hard to search and find some good introductory tutorial on SQL... Good luck Bye